# How to count data-id in tag a in jquery or just javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

[count data-id in one tag a](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4t9A.png) How can i get count my attribute id, in data-id or else by javascript?

Edit

Comment: Please try and re-phrase your question.  I have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: for example i have tag a, <a href="#" data-nilai1="sadadfasdf" data-nilai2="asdfasdfasdf" data-nilai3="asdfasdf"></a>, hmmm how to count that all "data-nilai" by javascript or jquery? like that..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're trying to parse all a elements and look for specific attributes that start with a certain string:

```
    $(function() {
        $("a").each(function() {
            $.each(this.attributes,function(i,a){
                if(a.name.match("^data-nilai")){
                    console.log(a.value)
                }
            })
        })
    })
```

As far as I'm aware there's no JQuery selector for searching for fuzzy attribute names.  Only values of attributes.

```html
<html>        
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
    <body>
        <a href="#" data-nilai1="sadadfasdf" data-nilai2="asdfasdfasdf" data-nilai3="asdfasdf"></a>
        <script>
            $(function() {
                $("a").each(function() {
                    $.each(this.attributes,function(i,a){
                        if(a.name.match("^data-nilai")){
                          console.log(a.value);
                        }
                      })
                })
            })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: greaatttt,, and how i could to show all attribut into form (textbox), example i have 3 attribute like above data, i wanna show all data into textbox?

Comment: Either concatenate the value of the textbox or have a running variable and do something like: $("#TextBoxID").val(variable);  Also: a.name will return the attribute name if you need it.